# Algebra book(s): Beginner through to advanced

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, self-learning

I admit, I am not great at Maths; I'm situated in one off the lowest Maths class for my year, partly due to myself losing focus last year. Though, I like maths, I really do. Especially since I do a lot of computer science with a focus on 3D (Matrix Maths). You have perhaps guessed that I am of a young age, well I'm one year off my AS year (American equivalent freshman year) and I would like to take Maths, mainly for computer science. Universities stipulate an A in maths to study computer science - hence my problem; I need to self-learn.

I will get the required Grades to get on the course (I hope), but it's the more advanced topics I feel will let me down. I am currently doing (Quadratics, unknown on both sides, solving equations and functions of equations).

Please, can anyone recommend beginner all the way through to advanced Maths/Algebra?

Comment: That looks perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beginning algebra, I like [Schaum's Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071452273). Everything is concisely written and the book is loaded with problems. You should be able to pick up a copy for much less than \$10 US (it looks like used copies are going for less than \$1).

Answer (score 3):

Algebra by Gelfand I think is a really good book. You will love it!
Another good book on algebra, at a higher level than Gelfand is "Higher Algebra" by Kurosh.

Answer (score 0):

[Solutions of the Examples in Higher Algebra (LaTeX Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150876350X) by Hall and Knight along with the textbook may be of immense help.